# Python алгоритм построения прямой и нахождение, точек лежащих на прямой

Tags: python, математика, graph

Вопрос касательно моего [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338482/python-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) вопроса, прошу с ним ознакомиться.

Суть задачи из точки проводить луч(прямую) от верха до низа и находить такое положение прямой на которой будут лежать минимум 3 точки. По X время в unix, по Y всегда 4 точки. (на картинке немного не так)
формат массива [[unix,v1,v2,v3,v4],[unix,v1,v2,v3,v4]...].

У меня не получается придумать алгоритм который бы выполнил задачу, помогите пожалуйста.

На GIF я намеренно пропустил несколько итераций чтобы не затягивать. Луч пускаем из каждой точи.

[image: gif]

Comment: Как мне кажется, рано или поздно вы наберёте лучей под любым углом. Первое, что приходит в голову - горизонтальные лучи соберут 4 точки довольно быстро. Дальше насобираются углы 1к1 2к1 3к1 ... Nк1. В общем, непонятен смысл всего этого.

Comment: В качестве алгоритма можно для каждой пары точек вычислить коэффициенты для уравнения прямой Ax + By + C = 0, а дальше искать среди троек пропорциональные, что будет означать, что прямые совпадают.

Comment: По-моему, типичнейшая [XY-проблема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY#:~:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20XY%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F,%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20X.)...

Comment: Вы пытаетесь придумать алгоритм2 для решения задачи вашим методом (читай алгоритмом1). Может, начните с вашей глобальной задачи, чтобы обсудить алгоритм1?

Comment: Из обоих вопросов не стало ясно, какова исходная задача.

Comment: Сколько исходно точек? Если мало, то перебираем тройки. Если побольше то можно за `NNlogN` отыскать все группы на прямых (муторно, но элементарными средствами). Если N ещё больше, то за NN (очень сложно).

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, по Y всегда 4 точки, по Х много этих четверок, нужно найти все прямые перебирая все точки, кроме горизонтальных и вертикальных линий

Comment: Много это сколько? Десятки? Сотни? Тысячи? С ростом масштаба задача становится от элементарной до совершенно неподъемной.

Answer (score 2):

А в чём проблема? Я не очень понимаю. Мне кажется, алгоритм очевиден:

1. Выбираем очередную тройку точек (методом полного перебора)
2. Проверяем, лежат ли эти точки на одной прямой.

И всё...

Полный перебор - три вложенных цикла. Если точек меньше ста, то цикл будет выполняться меньше миллиона раз - вполне допустимо. Нечто вроде:

```
for a in points:
    for b in points:
        for c in points:
            if (a != b) and (b != c) and (a != c) :
                # Проверяем - точки a, b и c - на одной прямой?
                . . .
```

Как проверить, что точки лежат на одной прямой, я надеюсь знаете?

Comment: как проверить точки на прямой да, но я запутался как именно реализовать цикл, почему то в этой задаче ступор.

Comment: `itertools.combinations(..., 3)` - выдаст все тройки точек.

Comment: @AlgiZ - "как именно реализовать цикл"

- Дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Перебор всех троек точек и проверка принадлежности их одной прямой - это первое решение, которое приходит в голову, но далеко не оптимальное. Комбинаций будет n^3. Вариант с пучками прямых (лучами) тоже n^3.

Более оптимальным будет вариант с построением прямых на всех парах точек. n-1 + n-2 + ... + 2 + 1 комбинаций.

- записываем уравнения всех прямых в виде y = kx + b (на первом же шаге отбрасываем векторы с одной нулевой координатой.)
- заносим в массив/список/словарь в виде "k_delim_b" => [[point1, point2], [point1, point2], ...] (так автоматом группируются все точки, принадлежащие одной и той же прямой)
- проходим по созданной структуре и выбираем те, в которых больше одной пары точек. (если правильно строить без повторов - т1 и т2-тN, т2 и т3-тN, ..., тN-1 и тN, то 2 пары точек - 100% три разные точки)
- выводим полученные точки.

Еще сильнее оптимизировать уже вроде никак.